# NSDataFormatter dateFromString results in incorrect output

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Here is my code :

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MM d HH:mm:ss yyyy"];
logDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[line substringToIndex:24]];
```

line consist of string : `"Mon Feb 18 09:25:53 2013: FAILED : Configuration-Update :`"

I get the date alone "Mon Feb 18 09:25:53 2013" and formatted it with `@"EEE MM d HH:mm:ss yyyy"` format.
I get an incorrect output : `"2013-02-18 03:55:53 -0000"` Time alone is printed incorrectly. I followed [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for specifying patters but still I am phasing this issue. I am not able to understand where it going wrong.. It would be helpful if someone finds the problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: try setting time zone to your formatter

Comment: The "incorrect output" is obviously the `description` output produced by NSLogging the NSDate object, rather than the formatted string.  You got exactly what one would expect.

Comment: Have you set the formatter behaviour?

[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all.. it worked by changing the code this way ..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MM d HH:mm:ss yyyy"];    
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];    
return [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MM d hh:mm:ss yyyy"];
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

When you just log using NSLog you get the UTC format (UTC consists of offset value, in India its standard time +5.30)that is yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss z , z is the offset added or subtracted to or from current time based on the locality.

For example

```
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

**Tue 02 26 05:38:00 2013**    //**"EEE MM d hh:mm:ss yyyy**"

**Tue 02 26 17:46:22 2013**  //**"EEE MM d HH:mm:ss yyyy"**

**2013-02-26 12:08:00 +0000**    //just logging using NSLog

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set timezone for a NSDateFormatter when you print resulting date like this:

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use as :

```
NSString *line=@"Mon Feb 18 09:25:53 2013: FAILED : Configuration-Update :";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE' 'MM' 'd' 'HH:mm:ss' 'yyyy"];

NSDate *logDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[line substringToIndex:24]];

NSLog(@"logDate->%@",logDate);
```

Comment: It was not working since the timezone was different. After setting timezone, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we take the log of the NSdate object that will show the date with respect to the timezone +0000 only. for that we need to format the date to our local timezone. like this..

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MM d HH:mm:ss yyyy"];
logDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"Mon Feb 18 09:25:53 2013"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSLog(@"Date %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:logDate]);
```

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MM d HH:mm:ss yyyy"];
        logDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[line substringToIndex:24]];
        [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
        NSLog(@"date is %@",logDate);

Comment: mistakenly u have taken logdate instead of this....


NSLog(@"Date %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:logDate]);